# Problem Organizing Assets in Vite Build Output

Tags: javascript, output, vite, subdirectory

I'm facing an issue with organizing assets in the output directory while using Vite for my project. I've configured the `output.assetFileNames` option to organize assets into subdirectories based on their types (css, fonts, img, js), but it's not working as expected.

this my **Vite Configuration:**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import imagemin from 'imagemin';
import imageminWebp from 'imagemin-webp';
// Specify the input and output directories for img minify
const inputDir = './src/assets/img';
const outputDir = './dist/assets';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: true,
        port: 8080,
        open: true,
        https: false,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
                changeOrigin: true,
                rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
            },
        },
    },
    css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                autoprefixer(), // Add CSS prefixes
            ],
        },
    },
    build: {
        plugins: [
            vue(),// 
            autoprefixer(), // Add CSS prefixes
            // Minify images
            imagemin([`${inputDir}/*.{jpg,png}`], {
                destination: outputDir,
                plugins: [
                    imageminWebp({
                        quality: 75, // Adjust the quality (0 to 100)
                    }),
                ],
            }),
        ],
        assetsDir: 'assets',
        minify: 'terser', // or 'esbuild' for esbuild-based minification
        sourcemap: true,
        cssCodeSplit: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                assetFileNames: ({ name, ext }) => {
                    // Organize assets based on file type
                    if (ext === '.css') {
                        return `assets/css/${name}`;
                    } else if (ext === '.woff' || ext === '.woff2') {
                        return `assets/fonts/${name}`;
                    } else if (ext === '.jpg' || ext === '.webp') {
                        return `assets/img/${name}`;
                    } else if (ext === '.js') {
                        return `assets/js/${name}`;
                    }
                    // For other file types, use the default output format with hash
                    return `assets/${name}`;
                },
            },
        },
    },

});
```

i was tring many thing but this is the colse structure with this config

**Project Structure:**

```
dist
 ┣ assets
 ┃ ┣ arslaner.jpg
 ┃ ┣ arslaner.webp
 ┃ ┣ index-gT3gkYz_.js.map
 ┃ ┣ index.css
 ┃ ┣ rawert.jpg
 ┃ ┣ rawert.webp
 ┃ ┣ SegoeUI-VF.woff
 ┃ ┗ SegoeUI-VF.woff2
 ┣ index.html
 ┗ vite.svg
```

**Expected Output:**

```
dist
 ┣ assets
 ┃ ┣ css
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.css
 ┃ ┣ fonts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ SegoeUI-VF.woff
 ┃ ┃ ┗ SegoeUI-VF.woff2
 ┃ ┣ img
 ┃ ┃ ┣ arslaner.jpg
 ┃ ┃ ┣ arslaner.webp
 ┃ ┃ ┣ rawert.jpg
 ┃ ┃ ┗ rawert.webp
 ┃ ┗ js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index-gT3gkYz_.js.map
 ┣ index.html
 ┗ vite.svg
```

**Issue:**
Despite configuring the `output.assetFileNames` function, the assets are not being organized into the specified subdirectories. I've checked the file extensions, reviewed the Vite configuration, and tried running a clean build, but the issue persists.

I appreciate any help in resolving this issue. If you need more information, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Assets

For the files considered *assets* – which s all files apart from the `index-….js` and `index.html` file – their locations can indeed be modified via the `assetFileNames`. If we look at [the documentation form `output.assetFileNames`](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-assetfilenames):

> | **Type**: | `Type: string| ((assetInfo: AssetInfo) => string)` |
> | --- | --- |
>
> […]
>
> When using a function, `assetInfo` is a reduced version of the one in [`generateBundle`](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development/#generatebundle) without the `fileName`.

And when we look at [`generateBundle`](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development/#generatebundle):

> ```
> interface OutputAsset {
>   fileName: string;
>   name?: string;
>   needsCodeReference: boolean;
>   source: string | Uint8Array;
>   type: 'asset';
> }
> ```

And if we look at [the source code of Rollup where `assetFileNames` is called](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/blob/d56ac63dc0452820272a0d7536340277f7db68bf/src/utils/FileEmitter.ts#L46-L48):

> ```
> typeof outputOptions.assetFileNames === 'function'
>   ? outputOptions.assetFileNames({ name, source, type: 'asset' })
>   : outputOptions.assetFileNames,
> ```

We see that `ext` is not a property that exists in the object parameter passed to the `assetFileNames`. This means that for your function:

```js
assetFileNames: ({ name, ext }) => {
```

`ext` will be `undefined` for **all asset files** and thus none of the code paths within the `if` statements will be visited. Instead, consider querying the extension yourself like:

```js
// …
import path from 'node:path';
// …
export default defineConfig({
  // …
  build: {
    // …
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: ({ name }) => {
          const ext = path.extname(name);
```

## Sourcemaps

For the `index-gT3gkYz_.js.map` sourcemap file, you'd need to use the [`output.sourcemapFileNames` Rollup option](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-sourcemapfilenames) like:

```js
// …
export default defineConfig({
  // …
  build: {
    // …
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        // …
        sourcemapFileNames: 'assets/js/[name].[hash].js.map',
```

Comment: thank so mush its work i appreciate your answer and your time thank you